# Problem with Operation on Border pixels of an image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to implement a demosaicing algorithm (interpolation) for a raw image with the Bayer pattern **GRBG**. The program logic was to use the neighboring pixels to assign the values to R,G and B channels(I have attached the code). I am having a problem for this logic at the border pixels. For example let ***i*** be the pixel at *(0,0)*, I need the value of ***i-1*** which is not present in the image. My question is there a possibility to work around this like masking i-1 and the others as 0 without adding an new border of zeros to my existing image.

Any suggestions will be helpful.
thanks.

```
    int rows = 256;
    int cols = 512;
    Mat raw_img(rows, cols, CV_8U);                 //////////////////////
    Mat image(rows, cols, CV_8UC3);                 //  BAYER PATTERN   //
    cvtColor(image, image, COLOR_BGR2RGB);          //      G R         //  
    for (int i = 0; i < raw_img.rows; i++) {        //      B G         //
        for (int j = 0; j < raw_img.cols; j++) {    //////////////////////
            if ((i % 2 == 0) && (j % 2 == 0))//top green
            {
                image.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] = (raw_img.at<uchar>(i - 1, j) + 
                                            raw_img.at<uchar>(i + 1, j)) / 2; //red

                image.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] = (raw_img.at<uchar>(i, j) * 2); //blue

                image.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2] = (raw_img.at<uchar>(i, j - 1) +
                                            raw_img.at<uchar>(i, j + 1)) / 2;  //green
            }
            else if ((i % 2 == 0) && (j % 2 == 1))//red
            {
                image.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] = (raw_img.at<uchar>(i, j));        //red

                image.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] = (raw_img.at<uchar>(i - 1, j) + 
                                            raw_img.at<uchar>(i + 1, j) +
                                            raw_img.at<uchar>(i, j - 1) + 
                                            raw_img.at<uchar>(i, j + 1)) / 2;//green

                image.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2] = (raw_img.at<uchar>(i + 1, j - 1) +
                                            raw_img.at<uchar>(i - 1, j + 1) +
                                            raw_img.at<uchar>(i + 1, j + 1) + 
                                            raw_img.at<uchar>(i - 1, j - 1)) / 4;//blue

            }
            else if ((i % 2 == 1) && (j % 2 == 0))//blue
            {
                image.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] = (raw_img.at<uchar>(i + 1, j - 1) + 
                                            raw_img.at<uchar>(i - 1, j + 1) +
                                            raw_img.at<uchar>(i + 1, j + 1) + 
                                            raw_img.at<uchar>(i - 1, j - 1)) / 4;//red

                image.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] = (raw_img.at<uchar>(i + 1, j) + 
                                            raw_img.at<uchar>(i, j + 1) +
                                            raw_img.at<uchar>(i - 1, j) + 
                                            raw_img.at<uchar>(i, j + 1)) / 2;//green

                image.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] = (raw_img.at<uchar>(i, j));//blue
            }
            else // bottom green
            {
                image.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] = (raw_img.at<uchar>(i, j - 1) + 
                                            raw_img.at<uchar>(i, j + 1)) / 2;//red

                image.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] = (raw_img.at<uchar>(i, j) * 2);//blue

                image.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2] = (raw_img.at<uchar>(i - 1, j) + 
                                            raw_img.at<uchar>(i + 1, j)) / 2;//green
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If statements inside a loop are very expensive. You would be better off writing 4 separate loops for your code here. The first and last element of each row, and the first and last rows, can be handled outside of the loop.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, Thank you for the comment, Instead of doing 4 separate loops, i Thought its better to add an extra border and do everything in a single loop(the second solution in this question). What are your thoughts on it? which would be more expansive? extra rows/colums or the extra loops

Comment: Adding a padding to the image is a good solution. It requires copying the image, which does incur a cost, but this is typically faster than including conditional statements inside loops. The fastest approach is as I suggested, but it's more code and more complex code. As always, there are tradeoffs... :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo, thanks for the suggestions. I have one more problem, I have posted it here, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63385267/problem-with-storing-an-image-after-padding 
Can you please have a look at it and provide some suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above stated answer works. But to prevent the hassle of using `min,max` with each pixel. It can be done as shown below with an Opencv function:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat img_rev = imread("C:/Users/20181217/Desktop/images/imgs/den_check.png");
        
    //number of additional rows and columns
    int top, left, right, bottom;
    top = 1;
    left = 1;
    right = 1;
    bottom = 1;
    
    //define new image with additional borders
    Mat img_clamp(img_rev.rows + 2, img_rev.cols + 2, CV_8UC3);
    
    //if you want to pad the image with zero's
    copyMakeBorder(img_rev, img_clamp, top, left, right, bottom, BORDER_CONSTANT);
    
    //if you want to replicate the border of the image
    copyMakeBorder(img_rev, img_clamp, top, left, right, bottom, BORDER_REPLICATE);
//Now you can access the image without having to worry about the borders as shown below
for(int i=1;i<img_clamp.rows-1;i++)
 {
  for(int j=1;i<img_clamp.cols-1;i++)
   {
     ...
    }
  }

    
    waitKey(100000);
    return 0;
}
```

More operations can be found here:

https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=copymakeborder#copymakeborder

Comment: Hello. Depending on image size, copying a full image to make "room" for borders might be longer (even way longer) than checking coordinates when accessing pixels. Choosing between the two solutions depends on how many operations will be done on the images + border pixels. (create borders once and do not check coordinates per pixel access VS check coordinates once for a unique pixel access)

Comment: Hello jean, by a unique pixel access, do you mean to make 4 separate loops(for the borders) and then checking the co-ordinates inside these loops?. i am going to generate the hardware for both these methods (might take some time) and I will get back to you with the performance implications.

Comment: Hello. What I meant is that using openCV functions to replicate border pixels requires to physically copy the original image into a place holder with bigger capacity (image + replicated border pixels). The price of such operation is worthwhile if many processing operations are later done on the image content. It seems you are speaking about VHDL/RTL hw acceleration for handling border pixels. For that case I"m pretty sure coordinates clippling as I proposed is the right way forward: no overhead of doing this in HW compared to image copying.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
image.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] = (raw_img.at<uchar>(max(0,i - 1), j) 
+ raw_img.at<uchar>(min(i + 1,raw_img.rows-1), j)) / 2; //red
```

For all you i +/- 1 , j +/-1: this way you "replicate" border values by simply sticking to the last value value in the X or Y dimension

As a side note, openCV includes different demosaic algorithm that will be hard to beat (for both quality and execution speed)

Comment: hello Jean, Thanks for your reply. indeed I have seen the demosaic algorithm available on OpenCV. The problem is I am trying to implement this for a vivado hls, which does not allow the demosiac by openCV.
Coming back to the question, I understood your logic, does "i-1" throw an garbage value? I thought it will give you an error as it is not possible to acces the -1 index position in an array.

Comment: Hello. using `max(0,i-1)` instead of `i-1` ensure that you always use a row index >= 0. So there is not worrying about accessing values out of the image dimension. This rules apply for any other pixel coordinate (using `min(i + 1,raw_img.rows-1)`) to not go past the latest row,...

Comment: hello jean, Instead of masking with zero, is it also possible to assign the nearest edge sample?? If so can you please give me an example??

Comment: Hello. When you use `max(0,i-1)` for row i-1 you indeed use row 0 if i-1 is negative so you replicate row 0. There is no masking involved here.