# problem with storing an image after padding

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am performing a simple masking operation with a 5x5 window. Following the accepted solution from this post [Problem with Operation on Border pixels of an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61686390/problem-with-operation-on-border-pixels-of-an-image) (second solution), I have created a image `img_clamp` which can act as a buffer with 4 extra rows and 4 extra columns. Please find the sample code below.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat input = imread("C:/Users/20181217/Desktop/images/imgs/den_check.png");
    //input.rows = 256, input.cols =512
    Mat output = (input.rows,input.cols,input.type()); //row and col = 256 and 512 
    
        
    //number of additional rows and columns you woluld ike on each side
    int top, left, right, bottom;
    top = 2;
    left = 2;
    right = 2;
    bottom = 2;
    
    //define new image with additional borders
    Mat img_clamp(input.rows + 4, input.cols + 4, CV_8UC3);  
        
    
    //if you want to replicate the border of the image
    copyMakeBorder(input, img_clamp, top, left, right, bottom, BORDER_REPLICATE);
    //img_clamp row and col size : 260 and 516


//Now you can access the image without having to worry about the borders as shown below

//start iterationg from the 2nd row till 258th row (this leaves 1,2,259 and 260th rows for the out of bounds access by the 5x5 window) 
for(int i=2;i<input.rows-2;i++)
 {
    //start iteration from the 2nd col till 514th col (this leaves 1,2,515 and 516th cols for the out of bounds access by the 5x5 window)
  for(int j=2;i<input.cols-2;i++)
   {
     
    temp_red = img_clamp.at<Vec3b>[0](i-2,j-2) + img_clamp.at<Vec3b>[0](i-2,j+2) + img_clamp.at<Vec3b>[0](i+2,j-2) + img_clamp.at<Vec3b>[0](i+2,j+2);
    temp_green = img_clamp.at<Vec3b>[1](i-2,j-2) + img_clamp.at<Vec3b>[1](i-2,j+2) + img_clamp.at<Vec3b>[1](i+2,j-2) + img_clamp.at<Vec3b>[1](i+2,j+2);
    temp_blue = img_clamp.at<Vec3b>[2](i-2,j-2) + img_clamp.at<Vec3b>[2](i-2,j+2) + img_clamp.at<Vec3b>[2](i+2,j-2) + img_clamp.at<Vec3b>[2](i+2,j+2);
     
     ...
     
     //store values in the output image which has the same the size as input image (i.e 256 and 512 (rows and cols))
     output.at<Vec3b>[0](i-2,j-2) =temp_red
     output.at<Vec3b>[1](i-2,j-2) =temp_green
     output.at<Vec3b>[2](i-2,j-2) =temp_blue
         
         
    }
  }

//Code for checking the output is matching with the golden data(ideal image)<---- the ideal image is from a different language halide, My goal is to replicate the same logic in c++

Mat diff = abs(ideal-output);

    Mat diff = abs(small_img - ideal);
    //cout << diff;
    int r, g, b, t, n,r_b,g_b,b_b;
    r = 0; //faulty red
    g = 0;//faulty green
    b = 0;//faulty blue
    n = 393216; //total number of pixels
    //_b  indicates the border pixels
    r_b = 0;
    b_b = 0;
    g_b = 0;

    t = 1;//threshold for the difference

          // printing out the difference between final image and ideal image (if any)
    for (int i = 0; i < input.cols; i++)//512 col size x
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < input.rows; j++)//256 row size y
        {
            if ((int)diff.at<Vec3b>(j, i)[0] > t)
            {
                if (i == 508 || i == 509 || i == 510 || i == 511 || j == 252 || j == 253 || j == 254 || j == 255) //border pixels(right most and bottom most of the image)
                    r_b++;//increment if its one of the border pixels
                //printing the pixel position which has the wrong value
                cout << "problem at (" << j << "," << i << ")  of red :" << (int)output.at<Vec3b>(j, i)[0] << ", expected value:" << (int)ideal.at<Vec3b>(j, i)[0] << endl;
                r++;//increment if the red pixel is faulty and not matching with the ideal image
                n--;
            }
            if ((int)diff.at<Vec3b>(j, i)[1] > t)
            {
                if (i == 508 || i == 509 || i == 510 || i == 511 || j == 252 || j == 253 || j == 254 || j == 255)
                    g_b++;
                
                g++;//increment if the green pixel is faulty and not matching with the ideal image
                n--;

            }
            if ((int)diff.at<Vec3b>(j, i)[2] > t)
            {
                if (i == 508 || i == 509 || i == 510 || i == 511 || j == 252 || j == 253 || j == 254 || j == 255)
                    b_b++;              

                b++;//increment if the blue pixel is faulty and not matching with the ideal image
                n--;
            }

        }
    }
    cout << endl << endl << "for a threshold of difference greater than " << t << endl << "total faulty pixels are(R,G,B) :(" << r << " " << g << " " << b << ")"<<endl;
    cout << " The border pixels present in the faulty pixels are :(" << r_b << " " << g_b << " " << b_b << endl << endl;
    cout<<" correct pixels that match with the ideal image = " << n;
    
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to store the output as the regular image**(not padded)**.
Everything is going according to the logic except for the last four rows and four columns. The output from the console is [image: console output]

I know that its going wrong at `(i-2,j-2)` while storing but I am not able to find a way around it.

Any help/suggestions on how to work around it will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're adding 4 rows/columns, but you only add 2 when creating `img_clamp`.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm,  two rows on top and two on bottom is 4 rows in total

Comment: But in the construction of `img_clamp`, you're only adding `2` to the number of rows and cols of the input Mat.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, Thanks for pointing that out, I took the code from a 3x3 mask filter and edited it, so i missed that part. I have updated it

Comment: "Everything is going according to the logic except for the last four rows and four columns." Please show what it is that goes wrong. "I know that its going wrong at (i-2,j-2) while storing" Please tell us! The more details you give, the more likely you are of someone seeing what the problem is. We cannot run your code as posted, so we cannot see what you are seeing. Make our job easier!

Comment: @CrisLuengo I have updated the information and when I was trying to explain in detail, I found where it was going wrong. It is a small mistake in the for loop where i used "input.rows" instead of "img_clamp.rows" which caused the problem for the last 4 rows and columns, it is now solved. Thanks for your suggestions :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with bounds for the `for loop`
instead of this

```
for(int i=2;i<input.rows-2;i++)//size =256
 {
    //start iteration from the 2nd col till 514th col (this leaves 1,2,515 and 516th cols for the out of bounds access by the 5x5 window)
  for(int j=2;i<input.cols-2;i++)//size =512
```

It should have been

```
for(int i=2;i<img_clamp.rows-2;i++)//size = 260
 {
    //start iteration from the 2nd col till 514th col (this leaves 1,2,515 and 516th cols for the out of bounds access by the 5x5 window)
  for(int j=2;i<img_clamp.cols-2;i++)//size = 516
```